# Android Ion library load bitmap image

Tags: android

How can load images from an url with ion ? Image should be a bitmap.

Example: `Bitmap image=Ion.with(this).load('url')`

How can I achive this ?

Library:https://github.com/koush/ion

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should probably do it asynchronously. Here is an example:

```
Ion.with(this).load("url").withBitmap().asBitmap()
        .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Exception e, Bitmap result) {
                // do something with your bitmap
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked.I have one more question.Do you know how can I clear ion image cache when user closes the app

Comment: Either Ion.getDefault(this).getCache().clear(); or Ion.getDefault(this).getBitmapCache().clear();
You can do this in activity's onPause()/onDestroy() method.

Comment: I got this error: "The type com.koushikdutta.async.future.Future cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files" Anyone got it too?

Answer (score 4):

It can also be loaded synchronously if needed. For example:

```
Bitmap image = Ion.with(this)
    .load("url")
    .withBitmap()
    .asBitmap()
    .get();
```